# Nested Foreach loop with diffrent list in knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, knockout.js

I have two list  first **SelectedServiceSubCategoryList**
which is declared as

```
self.SelectedServiceSubCategoryList = ko.observableArray([]);
```

and second **ServiceCategoryList**

which is declared as

```
self.ServiceCategoryList = ko.observableArray([]);
```

and the models of those list are given below
for SelectedServiceSubCategoryList

```
    function SSCategoryViewModel(obj) 
{
                var x = this;
                x.Id = obj.SCategory.Id;
                x.SC_Name = obj.SCategory.SC_Name;
                x.SSC_Id = obj.SSC_Id;
                x.SSC_Name = obj.SSC_Name;
                x.Value = ko.observable(0);
                x.IsSelected = ko.observable(false);
                x.CompanyID = self.Company.CompanyID();
                x.Value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                    self.IsEditingServices(true);
                    self.DrawServiceGraph(x);
                    $('#serviceIndustries .editButtonIocn .edit').click();
                });
                x.OnClickSlider = null;
            }
```

and 
for ServiceCategoryList

```
function SCategoryViewModel(obj) 
{
                var x = this;
                x.Id = obj.Id;
                x.SC_Name = obj.SC_Name;
                x.IsSelected = ko.observable(false);
                x.CompanyID = self.Company.CompanyID();
                x.SSC_List = ko.observableArray([]);
                x.IsValueChanged = ko.computed(function () {
                    var selectedList = ko.utils.arrayFilter(x.SSC_List(), function (o) { return o.IsSelected() && o.Value() > 0; });
                    if (selectedList.length > 0) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                }, x);
            }
```

and I am using data-bind attribute in HTML to bind SelectedServiceSubCategoryList using foreach

```
<ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion"
                        data-bind="foreach:SelectedServiceSubCategoryList">
```

and I want to bind **ServiceCategoryList** inside **SelectedServiceSubCategoryList foreach loop**

How can I establish the relation between these two lists.

Comment: Can you post the structure of single item in SelectedServiceSubCategoryList and single item in ServiceCategoryList and then post what is your expected result.

Comment: i want to use foreach of ServiceCategoryList  inside ServiceCatSelectedServiceSubCategoryList

Answer (score 0):

If both are declared on the same level, like below:

```
var viewModel = function() {
  ...
  self.SelectedServiceSubCategoryList = ko.observableArray([]);
  ...
  self.ServiceCategoryList = ko.observableArray([]);
  ...
}
```

Then you call `$parent` to get to the ServiceCategoryList.

```
<ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion" data-bind="foreach: SelectedServiceSubCategoryList">
  <li>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $parent.ServiceCategoryList ">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```